Want to improve the image quality and decrease the image size
There is an image that I am using for my project and I want to make it small (by reducing size so it looks fine) along with increasing the quality of image. I am using below code:

Code used is:
\begin{figure}[H]
 \makebox[\linewidth]{
    \includegraphics[width=.6\paperwidth]{Interim Report/sharpen_Disease_layers.jpg}  
    }
    \caption{Different layers created in Disease datasets}
  \label{fig:disease}
\end{figure}
\vspace{}


Unfortunately your code can't compile: a) important lines are missing, b) we have no access to your image. // How did you create the image? How should this "magic" happen to reduce its displayed size while enhancing its resolution ??

you are starting with a jpg so there is really no question to answer here, you can obviously change width=.6\paperwidth to be whatever final size you want but the image quality is what it is, if you need a higher resolution image you need to go back and generate the jpg bitmap at a higher resolution, or generate a vector (eg pdf) version of that diagram rather then a jpg or png fixed resolution image.

\vspace{} would generate an error
